# C++ no instance of function template matches the argument list

Tags: c++

I have a function that takes 1 int value as an argument. When tried to call it, I receive this error: C++ no instance of function template matches the argument list; argument types are: (int)

Here's my code and function call:

```
template <typename Type>
Type func(int N) {
    double n = 0.0;
    /*
      some function 
   */
    return static_cast<Type>(n);
}
```

Function call:

```
   std::cout<<func(2);
```

I tried changing the template to static double, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: How do you expect to resolve the type of template argument?

Comment: I'm sorry I didnt understand your question

Comment: When you call `func(2)` what do you expect the `Type` be?

Comment: You need to specify what type `Type` should be, e.g.: `func<double>(2)`. The compiler cannot deduce the type because none of the function parameters use it.

Comment: The alternative is to delete `template <typename Type>` and replace every other instance of `Type` with `double`. There might be a good reason but it's not obvious from the posted code why `func` is a template function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This call:

```
std::cout<<func(2);
```

Should be this:

```
std::cout << func<double>(2);
```

Or whatever type you're trying to convert to.